# JPA @SecondaryTable with Relationships not joining

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

Hi so I have this setup between two tables and two views. The views and tables are one-to-one with each other but I need access to both at all times and unfortunately cannot change my database. These two tables have a Many-To-One relationship. All tables and views have the same primary key names so joins between the tables and views are easy.

I have the following code

```
    //Model1.java The One
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TABLE_1")
    @SecondaryTable(name = "VIEW_1")
    public class Model1 {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue
       @Column(name = "ID")
       private Long id;

       public Long getId() {
          return this.id;
       } 

       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "m1")
       private List<Model2> m2s;

       public List<Model2> getM2s() {
          return this.m2s;
       }
    }

    //Model2.java The Many
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TABLE_2")
    @SecondaryTable(name = "VIEW_2")
    public class Model2 {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue
       @Column(name = "ID")
       private long id;

       public Long getId() {
          return this.id;
       } 

       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "MODEL_1_ID")
       private Model1 m1;

       public void setM1 (Model1 m1) {
          this.m1 = m1;
       }
       public Model1 getM1 () {
          return this.m1;
       }
    }
```

Then I use it like this

```
    Model1 m = Service.read(m1Key);
    List<Model2> m2s = m.getM2s();
```

But the sql that Hibernate JPA creates is

```
    SELECT ... FROM TABLE_2 t, VIEW_2 v WHERE t.ID = <m1Key>;
```

Instead of

```
    SELECT ... FROM TABLE_2 t, VIEW_2 v WHERE t.ID = v.ID AND t.MODEL_1_ID = <m1Key>;
```

So essentially the join between my primary and secondary tables is not happening when I get the list of many. If there is annotations or any setup you can suggest it would be a huge help.

Comment: Why exactly do you need the join there? It looks like you're just joining on the ID, which Hibernate knows already.

Comment: @chrylis yes hibernate knows the id but the first query returns 3710 rows where as the second one returns 7 (the correct value) b/c without the join the full product of the two tables are queried not the join of them

Comment: You'll need to post the entire classes, particularly including the ID fields.

Comment: @chrylis updated the post and this is just and example of what im trying to do but I have basically commented/changed my actual running code to be this simple so that I can solve the issue before adding all my other fields/relationship, one problem at a time haha